# Kivy Multiple Screen Transitions not taking place

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to builng a multiple screen kivy app in python. There are no compile time errors. App Compiles successfully. I am using Screen Manager in kivy to achieve multiple screens. On clicking the buttons no transitions are taking place. Please help me perform transitions. Here are actual snippets of my code.

**main.py file**

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmamager import ScreenManager, Screen

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class AuthenticationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AuthenticationApp().run()
```

**Authentication.kv file**

```
<MyScreenManager>
    MainScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'Second'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        canvas:
            Rectangle: 
                source: 'images/blue.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.25

            Label:
                text: 'Vigilantdsjkadhakjshdakjsd Dollop'
                font_size: '15sp'
                size_hint: 1, 0.20 


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.1

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Login'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_release: app.root.current = 'Main'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Sign Up'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Recover'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Reset'
                    font_size: '15sp'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.75

            Button: 
                text: 'Page'



<MainScreen>:
    name: 'Main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        canvas:
            Rectangle: 
                source: 'images/blue.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.25

            Label:
                text: 'Vigilant Dollop'
                font_size: '15sp'
                size_hint: 1, 0.20 


            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint: 1, 0.1

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Login'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Sign Up'
                    font_size: '15sp'
                    on_press: root.current = 'Second'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Recover'
                    font_size: '15sp'

                Button: 
                    id: login_button
                    text: 'Reset'
                    font_size: '15sp'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1,0.75

            Button: 
                text: 'Page'
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the screen manager a global variable

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmamager import ScreenManager, Screen

screen_manager = ScreenManager()

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

and return the screen_manager instance in the `build` method.

```
class AuthenticationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='login'))
        return sceen_manager
```

then in your `.kv` file any where you want to switch between screens. try for example:

```
Button: 
    id: login_button
    text: 'Login'
    font_size: '15sp'
    on_release: root.manager.current = 'login'
```